# How to get Flash SWF Url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash

How to get SWF url form a webpage using javascript. Actually I want to retrieve all SWF from a webpage, So I wrote an Greasemonkey Script that scans OBJECT, EMBED etc tags to get the swf url. My script works fine on most of the pages, but fails on this one http://www.elkspel.nl/spelletjes/Film+And+TV+spelletjes/Eva+Mendes+Opmaken.html this page is not having any Object, Embed tag in its source and my script fails here.

Is there any way to get SWF Url from any webpage??

Comment: It's got an `object` in an `iframe`.

Comment: but there is no SWF file URL in source. How to get the SWF url in this iframe?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the object tag is embedded into the page loaded into the iFrame. To get the SWF url manually, just grab the url of the page in the iFrame and open it in a browser. Automating that might be difficult though. You would have to do the same thing via code - grab the url from the iFrame and load the page.

You could also look through the Firebug /Net/Flash/ tab and grab the URLs for any SWFs there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is there any way to know if that specific Iframe tag contains object flash?, as loading each iframe in browser will consume time and bandwidth???